# what is the difference between $D(g\circ f)(x)$ and $Dg(f(x))$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $A$ be an open in $\mathbb R^m$. Let $B$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $f: A \to  \mathbb R^n$ and $g: B \to  \mathbb R^p$ where $B = f(A)$. If $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(a) = b$. Then $D(g\circ f)(a) = Dg(f(a) Df(a)$.

I got this theorem in Mukresh's Analysis of Manifolds . I can not understand what is the difference  between $D(g\circ f)(x)$ and $Dg(f(x))$ .

Can anyone please make me understand ?

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: A little tip. The composition operation is available as \circ

Comment: Do you mean *Munkres's* Analysis of Manifolds? Can you please double-check the other typos in your post, especially in the main formula you are asking about?

Comment: Write them as $(\mathrm D(f \circ g))(x)$ and $(\mathrm Df)(g(x))$.

Comment: Yes. ,,,,,,,,,,,.@Rahul

Comment: The fact that parentheses are missing does not help with the parsing of the question.

Comment: Still incorrect after the edit, but only in some places. At the end of the first paragraph, it should be $Dg(f(a))Df(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing parentheses, which makes your question hard to parse. Here is how I parse it:

> I can not understand what is the difference between $D(g\circ f)(x)$ and $Dg(f(x))$.

Think of it this way:
$D$ is an *operator*, which "takes" as input a function and outputs another function. Therefore, if $f$ is the input, then $D(f)$ *(often abbreviated $Df$, which does not help with the confusion)* is another function, the "output" of $D$ applied to $f$.

Therefore, $D(g\circ f)(x)$ is what you get when applying the function $D(g\circ f)$ on the point $x$. On the other hand, $Dg(f(x))$ is what you get when applying the function $Dg$ (that is, $D(g)$) on the point $f(x)$.

Put differently: $h_1= D(g\circ f)$ and $h_2= D(g)$ are two *functions*, while $x$ and $y=f(x)$ are two *points*. With this notation, you are asking about the difference between $h_1(x)$ and $h_2(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

- $D(g\circ f)(x)$ is the Jacobian of $g(f(x))$ at $x$.
- $Dg(f(x))=Dg(y)$ is the Jacobian of $g(y)$ at $y=f(x)$.

To give a concrete example assume

- $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)$
- $g(u,v)=(u^2,2uv,v^2)$

then

$$Df(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2x&2y\\2x&-2y\end{bmatrix}$$

$$Dg(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial g_3}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial g_3}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2u&0\\2v&2u\\0&2v\end{bmatrix}$$

and then at a specific point $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(u_0,v_0)=(f_1(x_0,y_0),f_2(x_0,y_0)$ we can evaluate the Jacobian for the composition that is

$$D(g\circ f)(x_0,y_0)=Dg(u_0,v_0)\cdot Df(x_0,y_0)=Dg(f_1(x_0,y_0),f_2(x_0,y_0))\cdot Df(x_0,y_0)$$

Comment: No they are not same. If they are same , how $D(gof(a)) = Dg(f(a) D(f(a))$. Please read the question?@gimusi

Comment: @cmi We can write $D(g\circ f(a)) = D(g(f(a))) = Dg(f(a))\cdot D(f(b))$.

Comment: @cmi You need to read again your question! You wrote $$D(g\circ f(a)) = Dg(f(a)) D(f(a))$$ what I'm claiming is that we can also write  $$D(g(f(a))) = Dg(f(a)) D(f(a))$$ Can you see the difference?

Comment: Yea I got you ...Can you please explain me what is the difference between $D(g(f(x))$ and $Dg(f(x)$???@gimusi

Comment: @cmi $\mathrm D(g(f(x))) = \mathrm D(g\circ f)(x), \mathrm Dg(f(x)) = (\mathrm Dg)|_{f(x)}$. You wrote wrong after the statement of the theorem.

Comment: @cmi Please, make sure what you write actually *can* be parsed. You write $D(g(f(x))$, which is bound to add confusion: it is ambiguous at best, or rather incorrect -- more opening parentheses than closing. You cannot ask about the meaning of something that is actually not mathematically correct. We can *interpret* what you mean, but then of course there's going to be errors in some of the interpretations.

Comment: @cmi $D(g(f(x))$ is the jacobian of $f(g(x))$ at $x$ while $Dg(f(x))=Dg(y)$ is the jacobian of $g$ at $y=f(x).$

Comment: For instance, I believe this answer to be incorrect -- writing $D(g(f(x)))$ is not a good thing ($D$ must be applied to a function, but $g(f(x))$ is a number -- the correct thing would be $D(g)(f(x))$). However, I cannot blame gimusi for this, since what you ask was also syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Edited....Can you please check if there is still any tyo?@ClementC.

Comment: Can you please double check your last comment and edit..@gimusi

Comment: @cmi I think it should be $\mathrm D(g \circ f)(x) = \mathrm Dg (f(x)) Df(x)$. Have a good look a  my notation.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes I used the syntax used by cmi. I usually write that as $$D(g \circ f)(x_0)=Dg(y_0)\cdot Df(x_0)$$

Comment: @cmi When you write them, bear in mind that $\mathrm D$ acts on functions, so $\mathrm Df, \mathrm D(g \circ f)$ are both valid, but not $\mathrm D((g\circ f)(x))$.

Comment: I edited....Now I think there is no error..@ClementC.

Comment: I edited....Now I think there is no error..@gimusi

Comment: Can you please now edit your answer and elaborate it little bit?@gimusi

Comment: @cmi I've revised a little bit and given a concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, you could rewrite them. Or write
$$
\mathrm D(g\circ f)|_{x}, \quad \mathrm Dg|_{f(x)}.
$$
Explanations: the differential of $g \circ f$ at $x$, and the differential of $g$ at $f(x)$.