# Using the chain rule in higher dimensions

Tags: analysis

In Uni, we started with partial differentiation etc. and I understand the chainrule in 1 dimension but I am totally stuck with the following:

Evaluate the Jacobi-Matrix by using the chainrule for the following function:

$$h(a) = f(g(a))  $$

$$ f(u,v) = u^3 - uv + v^3  $$

$$ g(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
x\cdot cosh(y) \\
y\cdot cosh(y) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

My attempt so far:

$$h(x,y) = (x\cdot cosh(y))^3 - x\cdot y \cdot cosh(y)^2 + (y\cdot cosh(y))^3$$

I could now easily evaluate the Jacobi-Matrix but I think this is not the way, the uni wants me to solve this.

> I understand how to evaluate $\dfrac{dh(x_1,x_2)}{dx_i}$ but I am stuck at evaluating $\dfrac{d(f(g(x_1,x_2)))}{dx_i}$

$$\dfrac{d(f(g(a)))}{dx_i} = D(f\circ g)(x_1,x_2)=Df(g(x_1,x_2))\cdot Dg(x_1,x_2)$$

But $Dg(x_1,x_2)$ would be a vector. Wouldn't it?
How could I keep going from here?

Comment: $Dg$ is a $2\times2$-matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$Dg(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
g_{1,x}&g_{1,y} \\
g_{2,x}&g_{2,y} 
\end{bmatrix}_{(x_0,y_0)}$$

$$Df(u,v) = \begin{bmatrix}
f_u&f_v 
\end{bmatrix}_{(g_1(x_0,y_0),g_2(x_0,y_0))}$$

and

$$D(f\circ g)=Df(u,v)\cdot Dg(x,y)$$

which is indeed a $1\times 2$ vector.

Comment: and just multiplying this out will return the Jacobi-Matrix?

Comment: @FinnEggers Yes of course, refer also to the related [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2874624/505767)

Comment: thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @FinnEggers You are welcome! Bye